# What is an element vs. a selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand the

> jQuery( element )

part of the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Q: Is this their example of what an element is:

```
$(myForm.elements).hide();
```

It's the last example in the section.
What is an element vs. a selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOM element is an element that has been fetched by a native browser method, such as `getElementById("element")`. A selector is a jQuery selector string, such as `#element`. Those two select the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) is a string corresponding to an element, eg `'body'`

Element is an actual DOM element, the actual object in the web page. A hard reference to one would be `document.body`.

$('body') returns an array of 1 element containing the body element. I specified the selector string `body` to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

an element is an actual tag, like < div > or < p >

a selector is an id, class, or type of element, like :input

Answer (score 1):

*Selector* refers to the [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) although jQuery have implemented their own on top of the standard set - even more than the current [CSS3 set](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

[**This**](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200508/html_tags_vs_elements_vs_attributes/) is a great explanation of what an *element* is (and how it is different to a *tag*)

Answer (score 1):

a jQuery selector is similar to a css selector - jQuery has to go out and find these in the DOM (depending on the complexity of the selector jQuery will use built-in javascript methods to get the elements or for complex selectors it will use the [sizzler selector library](http://sizzlejs.com/))

an element is a DOM level object such as `document.getElementById('someElement');` where the element is already ready for jQuery to "augment" with it's fancyness